# Laravel 8 Pagination with Filtered and Shuffled Search Results, Avoiding Duplicate Users on Next Pages

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel 8 project that involves searching for users based on various criteria such as language, expertise, timezone, price, and keywords. I have successfully implemented the search functionality with pagination, but I'm facing an issue where the same user appears on multiple pages.

Here's a simplified version of the query I'm using:

```
$query = User::Active()
$query->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN avg_price BETWEEN $minPrice AND $maxPrice THEN 0 ELSE 1 END");
$query->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN country_timezones.TimeZone = '$timezone' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END");
$query->inRandomOrder();
$users = $query->paginate(10);
```

The goal is to shuffle the search results to provide some randomness in the display, but also ensure that no user appears more than once across different pages.

For instance, if a user "John Doe" appears on page 1, they should not appear on page 2 or any other subsequent pages. This is to avoid duplication and provide a fair and unique representation of users on each page.

I'm looking for suggestions or a modification to the current query that would enable me to achieve this behavior effectively. Any insights or alternative approaches to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We do not kbiw your data, so it is a but difficult to suggest a solution! However, random order of rows and paginstion do not really go well together, as the order of the rows changes every time you run the query! You have to fix the random seed for a given session to have a repeatable random order. Also, multiple rows of the same group and pagination do not really work well together either. You cannot prevent these rows from being split over multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

In your query add seed to your random order.
And then pass the same seed to user frontend.

So, when user returns with a seeder it will always get back the same set of data that person has received and randomness will be followed.

```
$seed = $request->has('seed') ? (int)$request->seed : time();
//And add this $seed to inRandomOrder()
$query->inRandomOrder($seed);
```